# HTML SVG Not Drawing (Works in Other Pages)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

I'm calculating the values for a `path` and `circle` that are within an `svg` element using Javascript. I can get the right HTML code to be injected into the HTML page, but no circle/svg is drawn.

This is what is injected into my HTML by the Javascript

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="115" cy="110" r="50"></circle>
  <path d="M115,110 L115,0 A50,50 1 0,1 190,35 z"></path>
</svg>
```

If I copy and paste this code into a different `.html` file and run it, I get a shape (not exactly circular) that appears. This doesn't happen in my actual web page.

I can get the shape to appear if I put the above code directly in the html file (i.e. without using the Javascript function to dynamically calculate and inject it).

I am using Angular.js, if that makes a difference.

I don't think there are errors in my Javascript because the code injected into the html page works in other places, but I can post my Javascript code if that will help. There aren't any styles that would stop the SVG from appearing. It's almost like I need to tell the browser to reload/repaint/reparse the HTML, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help.

## Edit:

Here is my javascript code.

```
/*
<svg>
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
  <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 190,35 z"></path>
</svg>
 */
Sector.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Create our svg element
  var svg = document.createElement('svg');

  // Create and set up our circle element
  var circ = document.createElement('circle');
  circ.setAttribute('cx', this.startX);
  circ.setAttribute('cy', this.startY);
  circ.setAttribute('r', this.radius);

  //Create and set up our path element
  var p = document.createElement('path');
  var dForPath = this.dString(this.startX, this.startY, this.radius, this.angle);
  p.setAttribute('d', dForPath);

  // Add our circle and path to the svg
  svg.appendChild(circ);
  svg.appendChild(p);

  return svg;
};
```

and my usage

```
var sec = new Sector(115, 115, 110, 7);
var c = sec.draw();

document.getElementById('circleTest').appendChild(c);
// Weird issue. The following line makes the svg appear;
//  without it, the shape isn't drawn at all.
//  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347833/html-svg-not-drawing-works-in-other-pages
document.getElementById('circleTest').innerHTML += '';
```

Comment: @RobertLongson I've edited the question to include my Javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use createElement with SVG you must use createElementNS instead i.e.

```
var svg = document.createElement('svg');
```

should be

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
```

**And you need to do the same for all the other SVG elements you're creating.**

The innerHTML workaround that you've found will fix bu the namespaces but it's better to create the elements correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! Do I also need to use `createElementNS` for my `path` and `circle` elements? What is the `namespaceURI` that I need to use for these? Also, is there a better/more standard way to be inserting my elements from Javascript into the HTML?

Comment: Same namespaceURI as I've provided above. That's the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

I can get the shape to appear by adding the line

```
document.getElementById('circleTest').innerHTML += '';
```

below the code that was injecting my svg into `circleTest`. I'm not sure why this solved the issue.

Comment: after 4 years, I had the same issue and this workaround was the only way to make it work. Have you found why?